# MVC prevent updating certain fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using repository pattern and Entity Framework 6.

When I visit User/Details/5 page and update a users details, I get the following error -

> The property 'Password' cannot be set to a null value.

In my view, I have all these fields apart from Password, as I have no need for it in this view. How can I (essentially) tell MVC to not update the password in this view?

This is my UserModel

```
public class UserModel : IUserModel
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employee Number")]
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Type")]
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Login")]
    public UserStatus UserStatus { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Login Status")]
    public bool LoginStatus { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public int LastUpdateBy { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Full Name")]
    public string SurnameFirstName
    {
        get { return Surname + ", " + Firstname; }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my controller -

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(UserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _userService.Update(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

And my _userService.Update method

```
public void Update(UserModel entity)
    {
        User u = _userRepository.FindById(entity.Id);

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UserModel, User>();

        _userRepository.Update(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(entity, u));
    }
```

Comment: I think you shoud use ViewModel where Password property isnt define. It is not safe just remove property form view.

Comment: Is it ok to make Password nullable: `public string? Password { get; set; }`?  This would allow `null` to be assigned to `Password`, but it depends on how you expect the model to be used.

Comment: But then, if password was nullable, would it overwrite the existing password with Null?

Comment: Alternately, if you feel the need to leave things as they are, you would have to make a call to the database for the user, to set the password before sending it to your service.update.

Comment: What does your `_userService.Update()` method do? You should be pulling the `User` from the database, and copying over only the properties that are mutable during before calling `context.SaveChanges()` to update the `User` that was pulled from the database, not the model passed from the client. Something like saving the password should only be done with a specific method that gets called.

Comment: I have updated the post with my userService.Update method.

Comment: one of the error is to allow to reset password. AutoMapper is propably good, but before overwriting DB Password by VIEW password, you should check the provide password. Password should be handled out of auto mapper (note I never use autot mapper, maybe it can handle this case: not update field if null or empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key sentence is this:

`In my view, I have all these fields apart from Password, as I have no need for it in this view.`

You should define **ViewModels** instead of playing with the model (I know there is a lot of examples which do it like you, but the best practice is using viewmodels).

A ViewModel is basically a class which models your views so it only contains the properties you need. After you get this you can update your model as @krillgar said in a comment: pull the user from the database and update only the fields you want to update.